# Can a javascript variable be made configurable?

Tags: javascript

I defined a variable in my .js file and want the user/client to change that as per his needs. Is it somehow possible to use that value in forms in drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Too vague of a question, bring some examples of code.

It might go in a custom module (thus doing differently) or just using JavaScript where you can surely alter values of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to store configuration in code, not in the database. With that said, the following will add an arbitrary JavaScript snippet:

```
drupal_add_js(variable_get('your_variable'), array(
  'type' => 'inline',
  'scope' => 'footer',
));
```